# Facebook and MSN not connecting in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: empathy, facebook, msn

In 12.04LTS it all works fine but in 13.10 neither Facebook nor MSN connects. Seriously I wish Ubuntu will go back to Pidgin that just works fine without any issues.

Comment: You can still install Pidgin from the Software Center.

Comment: Yes, fb problem for me too.. but it should be reported as bug.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with Empathy and Facebook and this have been the case for a long time now.

Also since 13.10 I have been having problem with both Google Hangouts and MSN.

For Google Hangout : I get the notification that I have a new message but when opening the chat dialog I get now message (but can see it i gmail, g+ etc). Also the title bar says something about me having -1 unread messages.

For MSN: Does not even connect anymore.

It feels strange to have a default chat application in Ubuntu that really does not work very well. Remove it all together as default or fix it. In lots of forums people are recommended to use Pidgin instead, if that's the case Pidgin ought to be the default in Ubuntu from the beginning.